# Why sticky navbar's content doesn't fit in it?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have two styles for my navbar (.navbar and .navbar_fixed). And links in the navbar don't fit in it properly. I tried to remove padding and add `left: 0;` but it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar_fixed');
            $('.navbar_fixed').removeClass('navbar');
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
            $('.navbar_fixed').addClass('navbar');
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar_fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.global-padding {
 padding-right: 98px;
 padding-left: 98px;
}

.clearfix:after {
 display: table;
 clear: both;

 content: '';
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1366px;
}

.navbar {
 padding-top: 63px;
}

.navbar_fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 32px;
 padding: 23px 98px 0 98px;

 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.navbar__menu {
 float: right;

 list-style: none;
}

.navbar__link-item {
 float: left;
}

.navbar__link {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;

 padding: 10px 13px;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;

 color: #8c8c8c;
}

.navbar__link:hover {
 color: #212121;
}

.navbar__link_active {
 font-weight: 700;

 letter-spacing: 1.4px;

 color: #212121;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="global-padding navbar clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Interior Logo"></a>
        <ul class="clearfix navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link navbar__link_active">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">HISTORY</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">SHOWROOM</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__search"><img src="{% static "img/search.svg" %}" alt="" class="navbar__search"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="global-padding" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, ad tempore eaque autem at veritatis, modi a tenetur eius rem fugiat sunt esse! Placeat tempore quae quia eius alias! Ea officia modi cum sint pariatur architecto vero corrupti autem ex ratione asperiores commodi dolore fugiat, enim blanditiis quas accusamus sunt aperiam praesentium, accusantium excepturi? Ea, labore? Explicabo neque atque eveniet totam aperiam repellendus minima quia amet exercitationem laborum, quo tempore facilis dolores magni tenetur. Fuga nobis sit neque alias eos minima. Maiores quisquam soluta iure corrupti minima, ut enim error, ab nihil consectetur cupiditate, quod magni consequatur adipisci repudiandae architecto culpa suscipit! A minus omnis molestiae aut. Nam fugiat at, est voluptatem minus sint dolor commodi odio aperiam necessitatibus voluptatum ipsam nesciunt explicabo consequuntur nostrum hic, vitae eius blanditiis. Rem exercitationem, iure eligendi ullam accusamus, tempore impedit dignissimos perferendis quam iusto nulla molestias eos aliquam. Dolorum nisi atque nam! Iste vitae perferendis magni quos omnis impedit alias tenetur sed dolorem cupiditate totam sit nobis debitis blanditiis, cum ipsa, in earum ipsam. Asperiores atque molestiae fuga, quos tenetur repellat exercitationem magnam, voluptatibus aperiam dolore quisquam doloremque ratione perspiciatis autem in porro accusamus error accusantium iusto? Excepturi, pariatur repudiandae natus sed in totam voluptatibus laboriosam sint rerum nobis iusto quibusdam, perspiciatis alias ducimus quae dolorem eius, labore non ipsa quas. Tempore quis, beatae consequuntur explicabo asperiores eaque nisi ratione amet aliquid nesciunt atque? Enim laboriosam minima vero mollitia, quaerat porro facere laborum culpa molestiae perferendis? Quibusdam aut itaque, explicabo molestiae reprehenderit minima, et, soluta repellendus ipsam odio rem. Neque, dicta at voluptatum excepturi officiis vitae? Quidem debitis id sit amet recusandae facere rerum optio exercitationem necessitatibus cupiditate, illum magni ex reprehenderit fugiat culpa numquam maiores iste laudantium quasi ab neque! Quaerat consequuntur ipsa saepe quas perferendis consequatur neque rem pariatur corporis quia, enim eos dolorem reiciendis incidunt, ad architecto labore dignissimos adipisci sit in omnis cupiditate fuga? Blanditiis, maxime veniam quae ipsum labore ipsa quo necessitatibus, nostrum, magni omnis quidem voluptatum? Facilis vel reiciendis veniam consequatur dolorum minus! Blanditiis perferendis eveniet facilis. Assumenda corrupti libero eaque laborum labore expedita ab aperiam, neque fugiat id nesciunt dolore cupiditate reprehenderit, dignissimos distinctio ipsam. Minus sit, explicabo quae quos aliquam doloremque expedita consequuntur repellendus vel dicta? Dolorem aliquid placeat distinctio aperiam a aspernatur, ipsam quam minus doloribus, ad exercitationem quae? Ea iusto minus numquam fugiat inventore aspernatur perferendis temporibus pariatur nostrum cum eligendi, ab ratione modi similique quae rerum quasi tenetur dolor iure ut nemo molestias eveniet. Architecto soluta consequuntur optio quod, quos qui accusantium sit deserunt. Deleniti rerum explicabo sed. Voluptatibus, enim sit voluptas itaque quidem reiciendis asperiores quasi ipsum cumque consequuntur totam culpa suscipit natus repudiandae doloribus quas exercitationem veritatis sequi neque possimus qui voluptatum, nulla consectetur vel. Soluta reprehenderit perspiciatis debitis laboriosam, porro, possimus quis dolorem velit aperiam a aliquid blanditiis enim culpa dicta harum. Laborum reprehenderit enim est, eius laudantium quas ad molestias, quaerat debitis ullam quidem. Ut pariatur necessitatibus itaque at excepturi? Ratione, officiis amet repellat delectus recusandae eligendi quasi quidem esse similique quod at eum, placeat iure dignissimos magni modi debitis, nulla iusto facilis obcaecati ut. Sunt, delectus cumque aperiam exercitationem aut similique illum consectetur nostrum iusto iure aliquid impedit aspernatur dolore commodi. Asperiores saepe tempora architecto. Delectus dolorem distinctio obcaecati rerum eos eum fugiat ducimus, dignissimos, aperiam cupiditate non vel rem facere culpa eius doloribus laborum unde quod quos quae porro dolore natus. Et sed alias consectetur? Illo voluptatem possimus asperiores excepturi sed culpa dolore vitae est, esse laboriosam qui! Corporis, cupiditate ad tempore illo esse deleniti assumenda dignissimos mollitia eum odit dolores nostrum a odio maiores aperiam? Quisquam debitis perspiciatis expedita veritatis earum nemo modi eaque dolores nulla sapiente aperiam, assumenda magni quaerat iure nostrum cumque, repudiandae deleniti voluptatibus laborum! Perspiciatis quisquam aliquid nulla debitis doloremque, mollitia cumque ad totam quae suscipit, dolorum ratione perferendis consectetur magnam maxime facilis molestias quo impedit at asperiores, blanditiis et necessitatibus iure itaque. Ratione minus vero corporis mollitia velit ipsa quibusdam provident modi fugit suscipit, dolorem tempore? Recusandae ullam sit aspernatur sequi unde quas enim animi repellat perferendis rem nam praesentium, aperiam dicta eos temporibus quae! Laudantium placeat quibusdam consequuntur incidunt dolorem quia quos nulla sed aliquid accusantium quaerat consectetur obcaecati fugiat earum, laboriosam, inventore aspernatur amet at assumenda. Est dolore beatae non neque, ipsa ullam, perspiciatis laudantium ratione reiciendis vitae nobis veniam deleniti aliquam sapiente distinctio, voluptate enim praesentium fugiat libero repellat omnis ipsum. Veniam deserunt, ea in placeat distinctio facilis adipisci recusandae tempora iusto nisi excepturi sunt quae reprehenderit, tenetur enim, necessitatibus omnis et quisquam voluptate quia ipsum incidunt. Nisi sit ex mollitia aperiam nesciunt doloribus laborum rerum, dolorum deleniti asperiores ducimus maiores ea enim similique quas sunt? Sit fugit quibusdam adipisci culpa dolorum perferendis doloribus quo, placeat laboriosam expedita voluptatem totam dignissimos aspernatur aut soluta laborum! Repudiandae consequatur deleniti deserunt tempora error eveniet doloribus obcaecati, mollitia veritatis labore minima eum nihil ratione voluptate sit magni, voluptas quo exercitationem quia natus dolor. Cumque vitae ullam tempore hic fugiat esse a consequuntur libero asperiores minima cum earum repellat, ab, enim aliquam commodi saepe dolore nihil similique itaque laboriosam iure praesentium obcaecati! Eius, sed. In ipsam doloremque illum vel, sequi cupiditate, blanditiis dolores nihil aliquam veritatis facilis a impedit fugit cum, dolorum deleniti suscipit non velit laudantium ipsa maiores inventore nostrum animi? Error iusto, officiis saepe laborum nam repellat dolore aperiam ab deserunt distinctio quis amet vero, numquam obcaecati impedit quidem tempora corporis doloremque accusamus. Unde eveniet dolor quia maiores dolorem dicta. Veritatis nemo quos cum expedita doloribus, dolor recusandae soluta error, accusamus dolorum quis illo laudantium voluptatem aut repellendus optio, libero numquam eligendi enim totam distinctio. Sequi autem expedita eligendi vitae et quia dolorum adipisci. Expedita dolor tenetur, ipsa repellendus harum tempora aliquid delectus beatae quis ex cum sit sapiente hic deleniti incidunt ipsam repellat vitae. Porro distinctio, voluptatum rerum eius et corrupti fuga sapiente quia suscipit temporibus, nihil velit similique voluptatibus harum molestiae. Nemo, omnis quis facere ab nulla fuga tempore doloribus officia vitae commodi dolor, placeat voluptate beatae?
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-right to your navbar_menu

```
.navbar_fixed .navbar__menu {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your desired output?

Comment: try this new css and add media queries for the different screensizes

Answer (score 0):

I added class `.navbar__menu_fixed` and set `padding-right: 196px;` (doubled default padding), also I modified my script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar_fixed');
            $('.navbar_fixed').removeClass('navbar');
            $('.navbar__menu').addClass('navbar__menu_fixed');
            $('.navbar__menu_fixed').removeClass('navbar__menu');
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
            $('.navbar_fixed').addClass('navbar');
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar_fixed');
            $('.navbar__menu_fixed').addClass('navbar__menu');
            $('.navbar__menu').removeClass('navbar__menu_fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.global-padding {
 padding-right: 98px;
 padding-left: 98px;
}

.clearfix:after {
 display: table;
 clear: both;

 content: '';
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1366px;
}

.navbar {
 padding-top: 63px;
 padding-right: 98px;
 padding-left: 98px;
}

.navbar_fixed {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 32px;
 padding-top: 23px;
 padding-left: 98px;
 padding-right: 98px;

 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.navbar__menu {
 float: right;

 list-style: none;
}

.navbar__menu_fixed {
 float: right;

 padding-right: 196px;

 list-style: none;
}

.navbar__link-item {
 float: left;
}

.navbar__link {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;

 padding: 10px 13px;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;

 color: #8c8c8c;
}

.navbar__link:hover {
 color: #212121;
}

.navbar__link_active {
 font-weight: 700;

 letter-spacing: 1.4px;

 color: #212121;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="global-padding navbar clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__logo"><img src="{% static "img/logo.svg" %}" alt="Interior Logo"></a>
        <ul class="clearfix navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link navbar__link_active">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">HISTORY</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">SHOWROOM</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__link">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="navbar__link-item"><a href="#" class="navbar__search"><img src="{% static "img/search.svg" %}" alt="" class="navbar__search"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="global-padding" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, ad tempore eaque autem at veritatis, modi a tenetur eius rem fugiat sunt esse! Placeat tempore quae quia eius alias! Ea officia modi cum sint pariatur architecto vero corrupti autem ex ratione asperiores commodi dolore fugiat, enim blanditiis quas accusamus sunt aperiam praesentium, accusantium excepturi? Ea, labore? Explicabo neque atque eveniet totam aperiam repellendus minima quia amet exercitationem laborum, quo tempore facilis dolores magni tenetur. Fuga nobis sit neque alias eos minima. Maiores quisquam soluta iure corrupti minima, ut enim error, ab nihil consectetur cupiditate, quod magni consequatur adipisci repudiandae architecto culpa suscipit! A minus omnis molestiae aut. Nam fugiat at, est voluptatem minus sint dolor commodi odio aperiam necessitatibus voluptatum ipsam nesciunt explicabo consequuntur nostrum hic, vitae eius blanditiis. Rem exercitationem, iure eligendi ullam accusamus, tempore impedit dignissimos perferendis quam iusto nulla molestias eos aliquam. Dolorum nisi atque nam! Iste vitae perferendis magni quos omnis impedit alias tenetur sed dolorem cupiditate totam sit nobis debitis blanditiis, cum ipsa, in earum ipsam. Asperiores atque molestiae fuga, quos tenetur repellat exercitationem magnam, voluptatibus aperiam dolore quisquam doloremque ratione perspiciatis autem in porro accusamus error accusantium iusto? Excepturi, pariatur repudiandae natus sed in totam voluptatibus laboriosam sint rerum nobis iusto quibusdam, perspiciatis alias ducimus quae dolorem eius, labore non ipsa quas. Tempore quis, beatae consequuntur explicabo asperiores eaque nisi ratione amet aliquid nesciunt atque? Enim laboriosam minima vero mollitia, quaerat porro facere laborum culpa molestiae perferendis? Quibusdam aut itaque, explicabo molestiae reprehenderit minima, et, soluta repellendus ipsam odio rem. Neque, dicta at voluptatum excepturi officiis vitae? Quidem debitis id sit amet recusandae facere rerum optio exercitationem necessitatibus cupiditate, illum magni ex reprehenderit fugiat culpa numquam maiores iste laudantium quasi ab neque! Quaerat consequuntur ipsa saepe quas perferendis consequatur neque rem pariatur corporis quia, enim eos dolorem reiciendis incidunt, ad architecto labore dignissimos adipisci sit in omnis cupiditate fuga? Blanditiis, maxime veniam quae ipsum labore ipsa quo necessitatibus, nostrum, magni omnis quidem voluptatum? Facilis vel reiciendis veniam consequatur dolorum minus! Blanditiis perferendis eveniet facilis. Assumenda corrupti libero eaque laborum labore expedita ab aperiam, neque fugiat id nesciunt dolore cupiditate reprehenderit, dignissimos distinctio ipsam. Minus sit, explicabo quae quos aliquam doloremque expedita consequuntur repellendus vel dicta? Dolorem aliquid placeat distinctio aperiam a aspernatur, ipsam quam minus doloribus, ad exercitationem quae? Ea iusto minus numquam fugiat inventore aspernatur perferendis temporibus pariatur nostrum cum eligendi, ab ratione modi similique quae rerum quasi tenetur dolor iure ut nemo molestias eveniet. Architecto soluta consequuntur optio quod, quos qui accusantium sit deserunt. Deleniti rerum explicabo sed. Voluptatibus, enim sit voluptas itaque quidem reiciendis asperiores quasi ipsum cumque consequuntur totam culpa suscipit natus repudiandae doloribus quas exercitationem veritatis sequi neque possimus qui voluptatum, nulla consectetur vel. Soluta reprehenderit perspiciatis debitis laboriosam, porro, possimus quis dolorem velit aperiam a aliquid blanditiis enim culpa dicta harum. Laborum reprehenderit enim est, eius laudantium quas ad molestias, quaerat debitis ullam quidem. Ut pariatur necessitatibus itaque at excepturi? Ratione, officiis amet repellat delectus recusandae eligendi quasi quidem esse similique quod at eum, placeat iure dignissimos magni modi debitis, nulla iusto facilis obcaecati ut. Sunt, delectus cumque aperiam exercitationem aut similique illum consectetur nostrum iusto iure aliquid impedit aspernatur dolore commodi. Asperiores saepe tempora architecto. Delectus dolorem distinctio obcaecati rerum eos eum fugiat ducimus, dignissimos, aperiam cupiditate non vel rem facere culpa eius doloribus laborum unde quod quos quae porro dolore natus. Et sed alias consectetur? Illo voluptatem possimus asperiores excepturi sed culpa dolore vitae est, esse laboriosam qui! Corporis, cupiditate ad tempore illo esse deleniti assumenda dignissimos mollitia eum odit dolores nostrum a odio maiores aperiam? Quisquam debitis perspiciatis expedita veritatis earum nemo modi eaque dolores nulla sapiente aperiam, assumenda magni quaerat iure nostrum cumque, repudiandae deleniti voluptatibus laborum! Perspiciatis quisquam aliquid nulla debitis doloremque, mollitia cumque ad totam quae suscipit, dolorum ratione perferendis consectetur magnam maxime facilis molestias quo impedit at asperiores, blanditiis et necessitatibus iure itaque. Ratione minus vero corporis mollitia velit ipsa quibusdam provident modi fugit suscipit, dolorem tempore? Recusandae ullam sit aspernatur sequi unde quas enim animi repellat perferendis rem nam praesentium, aperiam dicta eos temporibus quae! Laudantium placeat quibusdam consequuntur incidunt dolorem quia quos nulla sed aliquid accusantium quaerat consectetur obcaecati fugiat earum, laboriosam, inventore aspernatur amet at assumenda. Est dolore beatae non neque, ipsa ullam, perspiciatis laudantium ratione reiciendis vitae nobis veniam deleniti aliquam sapiente distinctio, voluptate enim praesentium fugiat libero repellat omnis ipsum. Veniam deserunt, ea in placeat distinctio facilis adipisci recusandae tempora iusto nisi excepturi sunt quae reprehenderit, tenetur enim, necessitatibus omnis et quisquam voluptate quia ipsum incidunt. Nisi sit ex mollitia aperiam nesciunt doloribus laborum rerum, dolorum deleniti asperiores ducimus maiores ea enim similique quas sunt? Sit fugit quibusdam adipisci culpa dolorum perferendis doloribus quo, placeat laboriosam expedita voluptatem totam dignissimos aspernatur aut soluta laborum! Repudiandae consequatur deleniti deserunt tempora error eveniet doloribus obcaecati, mollitia veritatis labore minima eum nihil ratione voluptate sit magni, voluptas quo exercitationem quia natus dolor. Cumque vitae ullam tempore hic fugiat esse a consequuntur libero asperiores minima cum earum repellat, ab, enim aliquam commodi saepe dolore nihil similique itaque laboriosam iure praesentium obcaecati! Eius, sed. In ipsam doloremque illum vel, sequi cupiditate, blanditiis dolores nihil aliquam veritatis facilis a impedit fugit cum, dolorum deleniti suscipit non velit laudantium ipsa maiores inventore nostrum animi? Error iusto, officiis saepe laborum nam repellat dolore aperiam ab deserunt distinctio quis amet vero, numquam obcaecati impedit quidem tempora corporis doloremque accusamus. Unde eveniet dolor quia maiores dolorem dicta. Veritatis nemo quos cum expedita doloribus, dolor recusandae soluta error, accusamus dolorum quis illo laudantium voluptatem aut repellendus optio, libero numquam eligendi enim totam distinctio. Sequi autem expedita eligendi vitae et quia dolorum adipisci. Expedita dolor tenetur, ipsa repellendus harum tempora aliquid delectus beatae quis ex cum sit sapiente hic deleniti incidunt ipsam repellat vitae. Porro distinctio, voluptatum rerum eius et corrupti fuga sapiente quia suscipit temporibus, nihil velit similique voluptatibus harum molestiae. Nemo, omnis quis facere ab nulla fuga tempore doloribus officia vitae commodi dolor, placeat voluptate beatae?
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```